# getting value from controller to VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I have a function inside my apex controller :

```
public List<Decimal> getcheckProductMaxMinPrice(){
    List<Decimal> listDeci = new List<Decimal>();
    listDeci.add(5.0);
    listDeci.add(7.0);

        System.debug('Called ! ');

    return listDeci;
```

}

When I call it from my JS function inside my VF page :

```
<apex:commandLink action="{!addToTable}" oncomplete="doneAdding();" />

function doneAdding(){
   console.log("DEBUG : ",{!checkProductMaxMinPrice});

}
```

**on my debug log in apex :**

The only one call to my apex function "getcheckProductMaxMinPrice" is when I reloading the page.

When I hit the commandLink button - my apex function is never called.

Which means that the `" System.debug('Called ! ');"` will be printed on the screen only when I refresh the page (Calling the constructor) but not when I hit the commandLink button and the line `console.log("DEBUG : ",{!checkProductMaxMinPrice});` in my JS function is not calling the function even though I have a get before my function name.

So actually I have 2 questions here :

1. Why the function in my apex controller is called when I reload the page, if I call it **ONLY** when I hit the commandLink button?
2. Why this line : `console.log("DEBUG : ",{!checkProductMaxMinPrice});` does not call the function in my apex Controller?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your javascript rendered before your method is called? if you inspect the element what value do you see...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why the function in my apex controller is called when I reload the page, if I call it ONLY when I hit the commandLink button?

The code is called only when the page is rendered.

> Why this line : console.log("DEBUG : ",{!checkProductMaxMinPrice}); does not call the function in my apex Controller?

It did; when the page was rendered.

---

Your primary problem is assuming that the Apex method is called when the JS method is called, which is not correct. The Apex method is called *before* the page renders or re-renders. And, since you did not specify a re-render, the entire page reloaded, so the oncomplete method does not get a chance to execute.

The minimum changes you need are to add a `reRender` target, and that target should be the script in question. Here's what that looks like:

```
<apex:commandLink action="{!addToTable}" oncomplete="doneAdding();" reRender="scriptTag"/>

<apex:outputText id="scriptTag">
   <script>
    function doneAdding(){
      console.log("DEBUG : ",{!checkProductMaxMinPrice});
    }
  </script>
</apex:outputText>
```

Comment: Thank you ! Actually, I have rerendered attribute there - It's not specified here by mistake - but I have few more rerenders and that why it happened before.
Thanks for the explanation it helped me to understand something I probably didn't understand correctly.